# Sharing Keychain Items between two apps which has different AppIdentifierPrefix

Tags: ios, iphone, keychain

as i know we cant share keychain item with different AppIdentifierPrefix.but if anyone has different ans pl share

Answer (score 0):

there is no way (on a stock iphone) -- if the apps have different IDs, you're screwed here